# How to query mongodb with “like” using the java api without using Pattern Matching?

Tags: java, jsp, mongodb, servlets

Currently I am using java to connect to MONGODB,
I want to write this sql query in mongodb using java driver:

```
select * from tableA where name like("%ab%")
```

is their any solution to perform the same task through java,
the query in mongodb is very simple i know, the query is

```
db.collection.find({name:/ab/})
```

but how to perform same task in java

Current I am using pattern matching to perform the task and code is

```
DBObject A = QueryBuilder.start("name").is(Pattern.compile("ab", 
                                           Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)).get();
```

but it makes query very slow I think , does a solution exist that does not use pattern matching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DBObject A = QueryBuilder.start("name").is(Pattern.compile("ab", 
                                       Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)).get();
```

I think this is one of the possible solution, you need to create index to achieve those.

Answer (score 1):

Can use Regular Expressions. Take a look at the following:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions

Make sure you understand the potential performance impacts!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you fear the regular expressions? Once the expression is compiled they are very fast, and if the expression is "ab" the result is similar to a function that search a substring in a string.

However to do what you need you have 2 possibilities:

1. The first one, using regular expression, as you mention in your question. **And I believe this is the best solution**.
2. The second one, using the `$where` [queries](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-JavascriptExpressionsand%7B%7B%24where%7D%7D).

With `$where` queries you can specify expression like these

```
db.foo.find({"$where" : "this.x + this.y == 10"})
db.foo.find({"$where" : "function() { return this.x + this.y == 10; }"})
```

and so you can use the JavaScript `.indexOf()` on string fields.

Answer (score 0):

Code [snippet](http://dev.nirmalya.net/articles/java/equivalent-of-like-for-mongodb) using the **`$regex`** clause (as mentioned by **mikeycgto**)

```
String searchString = "ab";
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("yourCollection");
query.put("name", 
  new BasicDBObject("$regex", String.format(".*((?i)%s).*", searchString)) );
DBCursor cur = coll.find(query);
while (cur.hasNext()) {
  DBObject dbObj = cur.next();
  // your code to read the DBObject ..       
}
```

As long as you are not opening and closing the connection per method call, the query should be fast.